# jQuery plugins: How to explicitly call a jQuery UI function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery, jQuery UI, and jQuery Mobile on a page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
```

When I call

```
$("#slider-range").slider({range: true, min: 0, max: 100});
```

It invokes [jQuery Mobile Slider](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/slider/) (not intended)

How do I explicitly call [jQuery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range)?
(without changing the order of the included scripts because it will break other things)

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146868/jquery-ui-slider-conflicting-with-jquery-mobile-slider)?

Comment: Ah that's it! But I was looking for a more general way of specifying which function to call explicitly. There is no way to do that is there?

Answer (score 0):

Since both functions 'slider()' are added to the $() Object, you have to rename one function right after including the library

`$.fn.uislider = $.fn.slider;`

That's the way jquery plugins work, they extend the $ object. An other possibility is to edit the plugin itself, but I would not recommend this.